# create new guard in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm new in laravel and following a tutorial about create admin user in laravel so this is what i did:
I create `admins` table and then create `admin` model :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class Admin extends Authenticatable
    {
        use Notifiable;
        protected $guard = 'admin';
        protected $fillable = [
            'name', 'email', 'password','role',
        ];

        protected $hidden = [
            'password', 'remember_token',
        ];
    }
```

and then in `config/auth.php` create admin guard:

```
return [  
        'defaults' => [
            'guard' => 'web',
            'passwords' => 'users',
        ],



        'guards' => [
            'web' => [
                'driver' => 'session',
                'provider' => 'users',
            ],

            'api' => [
                'driver' => 'token',
                'provider' => 'users',
            ],

            'admin' => [
                'driver' => 'session',
                'provider' => 'admins',
            ],

            'admin-api' => [
                'driver' => 'token',
                'provider' => 'admins',
            ],
        ],



        'providers' => [
            'users' => [
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model' => App\User::class,
            ],
            'admins' => [
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model' => App\Admin::class,
            ],

            // 'users' => [
            //     'driver' => 'database',
            //     'table' => 'users',
            // ],
        ],

        'passwords' => [
            'users' => [
                'provider' => 'users',
                'table' => 'password_resets',
                'expire' => 60,
            ],
            'admins' => [
                'provider' => 'admins',
                'table' => 'password_resets',
                'expire' => 15,
            ],
        ],

    ];
```

and after that create the `AdminController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminController extends Controller
{   
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin');
    }
   public function index(){

      return view('auth.admin-dashboard');
   }
   public function showloginform(){
      return view('auth.admin-login');
   }
   public function login(Request $request){

     $this->validate($request , [
           'email' => 'required|email',
           'password' => 'required|min:5'
        ]);

     if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email , 'password' => $request->password] , $request->remember)) {

          return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
     }
      return redirect()->back($request->only('email','remember'));
   }
}
```

and in final step i create routes in `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'] , function(){
  Route::get('/' , 'Auth\AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
  Route::get('/login' , 'Auth\AdminController@showloginform')->name('admin.login');
  Route::post('/login' , 'Auth\AdminController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
});
```

the purpose of this tutorial was when i login as user i should not can access to `/admin` but i can and when you login as admin you should access to `/admin` that it shows the admin dashboard but i cant
any one can explain what is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `middleware auth` in order to restrict access in specific routes.
In your case it is `'middleware' => 'auth:users'` and `'middleware' => 'auth:admins'`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth:admins'] , function(){
  // here all routes will be accessible if admin.
});
```

Comment: when i login as admin it redirect me to home page why? its should show the admin.dashboard route but redirect it to home page